# Reflection in a UserControl to examine containing form. C#

Tags: c#, reflection, user-controls

my project is written in c#. I have a usercontrol that I've designed. In that usercontrol I want the ability to look through the form the control is placed on using reflection to look at all other controls on the form.

How can I go about doing this? I've used reflection to go through dll's but not for something like this.

in summary: My usercontrol is placed on a form, I want my usercontrol to onLoad look through all other controls on the form (sometimes i'll want to limit it to same container and not entire form but I can figure that out later).

I'm also open to ideas that dont use reflection if anyone has any.

thanks!

EDIT:

So i tried simply looking through the parent controls and that didnt work for what im trying to do, which is my fault for badly explaining it above.

Let me give some more details.

I know that on the main form there will be a ContainerListView control, now when you add columns to the containerlistview ContainerListviewColumnHeaders's are created. Their declarations show up in the initalizeComponent() for the form. What I want to do is in my usercontrol I want to look at the form and find all of the ContainerListViewColumnHeader's, however since they are not of type 'Control' (they are 'Component') they dont show up in the previous method. 
Interrogating the Containerlistview is not an option.

Comment: Couldn't you simply retrieve the parent form via the `Parent` property (possibly you'd need to subscribe to the `ParentChanged` event) and then access this form's `Controls` collection?

Comment: Concerning the additional info you give in your edit: AFAIK, a form doesn't necessarily have references to all _components_ added to it in the Forms Designer. Some components are initialized with a reference to the form, but not vice versa.

Comment: So using the approach provided by Reed I think you can find that ContainerListView control which will most likely have property like "Columns" and each column will have something like "Header". Just an assumption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for reflection.

Just look at [UserControl.ParentForm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.parentform.aspx) - this is the Form that's hosting the UserControl.  From there, you can iterate (recursively) through [Form.Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls.aspx).